# How to hide Taskbar in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry, regedit

I have been searching and trying for 3 days and still couldnt able to just hide the Windows taskbar. I have tried

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"QuickLaunchEnabled"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]
"Shell"=REG_SZ:00000001
```

None worked. What is the correct way to do it ?

Comment: Do you want to enable the "Auto-hide" option for the taskbar?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Right-click on the task bar, select Properties, and check the "Auto-hide taskbar" box. Also, this question belongs on SuperUser.

Comment: No, I need to do it in a programmatic way. Thanks.

Comment: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects2` source: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/auto-hide-taskbar-windows

Comment: @DavidRuhmann - Further Googling shows that while the reg key is correct, there's nothing in that link that indicates that you need to change the 03 after the first set of `ff`s to a 02, and that you need to either reboot or restart explorer.exe after you update the value.

Comment: Thanks somethingdark. How can I do it in a programatic way ?

Answer (score 1):

we had a legacy app at this company i was contracting at, so we developed a .vbs login script to do this.  added it to a login scripts, script will hide it and not put it back when the user logs back in.

```
Wscript.Sleep 5000

' ***************************************************************************************
' AutoHideTaskbar.vbs   
' This script enables or disables the "Auto-Hide the taskbar" option by sending Alt+u key
' when the tray properties are been opened
' Modify the variable cSendKeyValue with any of the values below
' %l - Alt+l - Lock the taskbar
' %u - Alt+u - Auto-hide the taskbar
' %t - Alt+t - Keep the taskbar on top
' %g - Alt+g - Group similar taskbar buttons
' %q - Alt+q - Show Quick launch
' %k - Alt+k - Show the clock
' %h - Alt+h - Hide inactive icons
' ***************************************************************************************

Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set Wshshell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.shell")
set fso = createobject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
Set WshSysEnv = WshShell.Environment("system")
Set WshSysEnv2 = WshShell.Environment("PROCESS")

' CHECK TO SEE IF USER AUTO-HIDE ALREADY RUN AND SKIP IF SO TO NOT UNDO WHAT WAS SET
If fso.FileExists("C:" & WshSysEnv2("HOMEPATH") & "\autohide.txt") then
    WScript.Quit
        else

cSendKeyValue = "%u"        ' Alt+u = Auto-hide the taskbar 
Set WshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.shell") 
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
oShell.TrayProperties 

Wscript.Sleep 500 
WshShell.SendKeys cSendKeyValue                        

Wscript.Sleep 250 
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"           ' Enter to Close Properties 

Set oShell = Nothing 

strOutputFile = "C:" & WshSysEnv2("HOMEPATH") & "\autohide.txt"
            Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.fileSystemObject")
            Set objOutputFile = objFileSystem.CreateTextFile(strOutputFile, TRUE)
            objOutputFile.WriteLine("True")
            End If
            objOutputFile.Close
            Set objFileSystem = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little old, but I did want to post a solution (since it shows up in Google). This user made a neat script that executes the toggling function in a Windows executable: http://www.mim-sraga.hr/zvuk/toggleTaskbarAutohide.htm

Very handy and does exactly what I need. Sounds like it's a good solution for you too.